# Date Time exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

I made a registration page where users input personal details to make an account. But I keep getting an exception and my application with the control validation do not work at all!!

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Registration _m = new Registration();
    DateTime dateOfBirth = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDOB.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
    lblMsg.Text = _m.Register(txtUser.Text, txtTitle.Text, txtPass.Text, 
    txtMidI.Text, txtSur.Text, txtCity.Text, txtPostCode.Text, txtxMobile.Text, 
    txtLandL.Text, txtEmail.Text, RBLMF.SelectedValue, dateOfBirth, 
    RBLYesNo.SelectedValue, txtSQ.Text, txtxAn.Text);
}
```

Exception says :

> ```
>  String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
> ```

Comment: What was the datetime string you were trying to parse?

Comment: For starters, you should use the debugger or stacktrace to look up where exactly the code is failing, though in this case it's most likely your single call to `DateTime.ParseExact`. The string you're trying to make a date is not in the expected format. What string are you using?

Comment: Date Of Birth can be inserted within the text box dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: `Chris` what is the actual format.. for example `05/11/2014` that's what we are talking about what does date value that you are trying to parse look like also [MSDN DateTime.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) look at that and notice how it utilizes the `out` Param

Comment: Calling ParseExact will result always in an exception if your user types anything that is not in the exact mask typed. You should try to use TryParseExact as pointed by @DJKRAZE and absolutely add a RangeValidator of type Date to your TextBox

Comment: So How would it be because I am a bit confused !:(

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your conversion from string to date is failing. Since you're pulling this data from a textbox, that means the input could theoretically be anything, so you should always validate it. Take a look at [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx). I haven't tested this code, but roughly what you want to do is change

```
DateTime dateOfBirth = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDOB.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

To

```
DateTime dateOfBirth;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDOB.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateOfBirth)))
{
  //Do your logic in here
  //.....
}
else
{
  //Show a message to the user that they didn't enter a valid date
  //.....
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Using "d/M/yyyy" is more flexible since it allows users to enter single-digit month and day.

Comment: how does this help the `OP` so what happens when the day is 2 digits..? the op wants to format with `dd` not `d`

Comment: @DJKRAZE it helps a bit. a mask "d/M/yyyy" accepts also "30/11/2014", however this should be handled by a TryParseExact